# Gerar hora aleatoria dentro de um intervalo

Tags: php, datetime, data

Tenho uma função que gera o horário atual, horário +12hs e horário +24hs.

Preciso que ele gere um horário aleatório dentro desse intervalo de 12 e 24 horas.

Tenho o seguinte:

```
//DEFINE HORARIO DE BRASILIA
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
//HORARIO AGORA
$agora = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());

//HORÁRIO AGORA +12 HORAS
$dataliberacao12= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+12 hours', time()));

//HORÁRIO AGORA +24 HORAS
$dataliberacao24= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', time()));

//RESULTADOS
echo 'Horário que concluiu: '.$agora.'<br/>';
echo 'Horario liberção 12h: '.$dataliberacao12.'<br/>';
echo 'Horario liberção 24h: '.$dataliberacao24;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ué, não poderia usar direito no `+12 hours`?

```
$dataGerada = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+' . random_int(720, 1440) . ' minutes', time()));
```

Se quiser só hora, sem alterar os minutos (mantendo os mesmos minutos/segundos do horário atual) seria ainda mais simples:

```
$dataGerada = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+' . random_int(12, 24) . ' hours', time()));
```

O `random_int(12, 24)` iria gerar uma hora entre +12 até +24, exatamente o que descreveu na pergunta. Usar o `random_int(720, 1440)` também geraria um horário entre +12 horas (720 minutos) até +24 horas (1440 minutos), porém iria gerar os minutos.

Comment: show, usei a primeira opção, deu certinho, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode gerar uma data e hora aleatórios usando a função rand() ou mt_rand() definindo o mínimo e máximo (strtotime das datas min e max).

```
//DEFINE HORARIO DE BRASILIA
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
//HORARIO AGORA
$agora = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());

//HORÁRIO AGORA +12 HORAS
$dataliberacao12= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+12 hours', time()));

//HORÁRIO AGORA +24 HORAS
$dataliberacao24= date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime('+24 hours', time()));

// Horario aleatorio entre os intervalos
$dataAleatoria = rand( strtotime(date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataliberacao12))), strtotime(date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataliberacao24))));
$dataAleatoria = mt_rand( strtotime(date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataliberacao12))), strtotime(date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataliberacao24))));

echo 'Horario aleatorio: '.date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $dataAleatoria ).'<br>';

//RESULTADOS
echo 'Horário que concluiu: '.$agora.'<br/>';
echo 'Horario liberção 12h: '.$dataliberacao12.'<br/>';
echo 'Horario liberção 24h: '.$dataliberacao24.'<br/>';
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta. testei aqui, ele está gerando o dia aleatorio tbm

Comment: Editei a resposta @LeandroMarzullo, tenta dessa forma

Comment: opa, deu certo tbm, vlw!!!